# Crop Image getting height and width on the move of cropper

Tags: android, android-crop

In Cropping Image,it is a requirement that on the move of cropper height and width automatically adjust according to cropper height width. if there is any lib pls suggest me.

i tried most of libs but not meet my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this, you can use this library it also has tons of other features too

implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'

```
CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                //   .setInitialCropWindowPaddingRatio(.5)
                .setAspectRatio(40, 40)
                .start(User_profile_settings.this);
```

You can set aspect ratio.